# How to get the day with zeros in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how I can get the day from a datetime column in sql server, I'm using the funcion **DAY** but it's giving me the day without the zeros for example:

```
Column: 2014-08-20 10:28:20.6470000
SELECT DAY(COLUMN) FROM TABLE = 8
```

What I expect is something like:

```
SELECT DAY(COLUMN) FROM TABLE  = 08
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `08` is the value you are looking for when asking for the day of the month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is the Format() if 2012+

```
Select Format(COLUMN,'dd')
```

I should add, Format() is not know for its performance, but it does have some nice functionality.

Comment: Thanks! :D. Now, what format should I use if I want the same but for months?

Comment: @NicolasSantisteban See... you've got it!

Comment: @NicolasSantisteban FYI, you can mix statements in format for example MMM-DD for Nov-22

Answer (score 3):

Return type of [**`DAY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) function is `INT`. So it will not include leading 0 in result. Try this

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+cast(DAY(COLUMN) as varchar(2)),2) FROM TABLE -- 08
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(convert(varchar(10),cast(COLUMN as date),3),2)
```

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Updated.. just got confused with OP's result. For the first query `0` should be used as string

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - still returns `20` as result. `SET dateformat dmy

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Cast('2014-08-20 10:28:20.6470000' AS DATE), 3), 2)`

Comment: My bad. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date to `British/French` standard or any standards that starts with day and select first 2 characters.

**Query**

```
select convert(varchar(2),[date_column], 3)
from [your_table_name];
```